# How fast does $a_n\to 0$ if $\sum a_n=1$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence, rate-of-convergence

Let $a_n\ge 0.$ If $\sum a_n$ converges, say to 1 (such as a probability mass function), then by the Divergence Test we have $\lim_n a_n=0. $ However, can we say how fast it converges?

I was thinking of using the integral test but that only applies for decreasing sequences.

Comment: Consider the sequence of sequences $a^{(i)}_n$ where $a^{(i)}_n=\begin{cases}1&\text{if}~i=n\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$.  That is the sequence of sequences $(1,0,0,\dots),(0,1,0,0,\dots),(0,0,1,0,\dots),\dots$.

Comment: Can we say whether the sequence $a_n$ converges faster than those sequences $b_n$ which approach zero but have $\sum b_n$ diverge?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no. We cannot say anything about the speed of convergence. We can only say that $a_n\to0$ as $n\to\infty$. This is a question about the nonexistence of the boundary between convergent and divergent series (see [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/49415/nonexistence-of-boundary-between-convergent-and-divergent-series) for more details).

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't.
Think about the series, $C(k)=\sum_n\frac{1}{n^k}$, $C(k)>1$ are some constants. Then
$\sum_n\frac{1}{C(k)n^k}=1$, but the decay rate of $\frac{1}{C(k)n^k}$ varies for different $k$.

Also, consider sequence $\{1,0,0,\cdots\}$ as JMoravitz mentioned in the comment, where already $a_k=0$ for $k>1$.